# Itertools.product buiding intermediary results in memory?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have the following code

```py
from itertools import product
from time import sleep
def slowrange(n,t):
        for i in range(n):
                sleep(t)
                yield i

for n,w in product(slowrange(5,0.2),"AB"):
        print(n,w)
```

since in the [itertools.product doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) says that:

> This function is roughly equivalent to the following code, **except
>   that the actual implementation does not build up intermediate results
>   in memory**

i would expect that i would see two lines with `0 A \n 0 B` then 0.2 seconds later i would see the following iteration, however, that does not occur, after 1s all the iterations are printed, if i use the following function instead of itertools.product, it does perform the desired behavior:

```py
def product(itertor1,iterator2):
        for s in iterator1:
                for f in iterator2:
                        yield s,f
```

So, what's going on?, is this a bug?, it is something wrong in the docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intermediate results are not built up in memory, no. That's referring to this part in the Python code:

```
result = [[]]
for pool in pools:
    result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
```

What *does* happen is that the input iterators are converted to tuples in a pool, the first lines:

```
pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
```

The pools are not intermediate results. Your `slowrange()` is first consumed into a tuple (and another tuple is created from the characters in the `"AB"` string), and from the tuples in the pool the results are produced (using an array of indices into those tuples).